# Fetch Next.js API in a component

Tags: next.js

I am super new to Next.js and I am struggling with API routes, or to be exact, how to get data out of those. I have written my serverless function in /api/weather.js

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
const city = req.query.city;
const getWeatherData = await fetch(
    `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/search.json?key=${process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY}&q=${city}&days=5&aqi=no&alerts=no`
  );
  const data = await getWeatherData.json();
  res.status(200).json(data)
  console.log(city)
}
```

City is undefined, as I was hoping to search city through my input field in a component SearchBar.js. For now http://localhost:3000/api/cities just returns an empty array, cause, of course, I need a city name to get the city. However the city name should come from SearchBar.js. However I didn't come far there. I have a query, but this is not connected to my API whatsoever.

```
export const SearchBar = () => {

const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
    const onChange = (e) => {
      const {value} = e.target;
      setQuery(value)
      

      let matchingCities = []

      if(value.length > 3) {
        const test = fetch('/api/cities', {
          method: 'GET'
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        console.log(test)
        //test returns a promise pending
      }
    }

  return(
    <div className="sm:col-span-2">
      <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
        Search city
      </label>
      <div className="mt-1">
        <input
          onChange={onChange}
          id="city"
          name="city"
          type="text"
          value={query}
          autoComplete="city"
          className="py-3 px-4 block w-full shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 border-gray-300 rounded-md"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I know that might be way too complex, but maybe someone could at least describe the necessary steps, to connect those get this query work for a city inside my input.

Comment: `req.query.city` is `undefined` because you're not passing any query param when making the API call from `SearchBar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the steps are:

- Your search bar in the browser page sends the request with the city name to your own API endpoint on the server
- Your API function takes the city name, and sends the request to the weather provider (with the secret key)
- When it gets the response, it responds to the original request, forwarding the data
- Your browser receives the response and does something useful with it

A couple things to fix:

- name of the endpoint: you have `/api/weather.js`, so in the SearchBar you should call `/api/weather`, not `/api/cities`
- your api expects the `city` parameter, so you need to pass it the value from the input: `/api/weather?city=${value}`
- maybe use `await` instead of `.then`, makes it easier to read (but that's optional)

See the working example here (check the console for output):
https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-api-with-lewagon-autocomplete-xrb3l?file=/components/SearchBar.jsx

I used LeWagon's API instead of the weather sevice, it doesn't require a key :)

Comment: Thanks LeWagon fellow! Yes, I kinda figured it out with the value yesterday. Just trying to access the response in my component. Such a headache!